# How to forward packets from one network interface via another interface

Tags: networking, routes, containers, iptables, ifconfig

> See picture below for architecture.

I know there are a lot of similar questions. However, having read multiple posts and trying some out I am still unable to set up as required. So I am posting this as a new question.

***Scenario:***

- I have three containers (**c1**, **c2** and **c3**)
- I have different interfaces each running in three containers (**eth0** and **peervpnXX**)
- *c1* has interfaces: **eth0** and **peervpn12**
- *c2* has interfaces: **eth0** and **peervpn12** and **peervpn23**
- *c3* has interfaces: **eth0** and **peervpn23**

Whilst **eth0** interfaces are on the same subnet the **peervpnXX** interfaces are on different subnets:

- *peervpn12* - 10.12.0.0/24
- *peervpn23* - 10.23.0.0/24

***Note that the peervpnXX interfaces are tunnel interfaces running on top of the eth0***

Now the ip_addresses assigned to each container are as follows:

- *c1* : 172.17.0.2 **(eth0)** and 10.12.0.2 **(peervpn12)**
- *c2* : 172.17.0.3 **(eth0)** and 10.12.0.1 **(peervpn12)** and 10.23.0.1 **(peervpn23)**
- *c3* : 172.17.0.4 **(eth0)** and 10.23.0.2 **(peervpn23)**

What I am trying to do is to enable **c1** to communicate to **c3** via the middleman **c2**. In principle, I am trying to:

- route packets intended to **10.23.0.0/24** from **c1** to **c3** via ***c2***.
- route packets intended to **10.12.0.0/24** from **c3** to **c1** via ***c2***.

I created a routing rule on *c1* & *c3* to send packets to subnets **10.23.0.0/24** & **10.12.0.0/24** via interfaces *peervpn12* and *peervpn23*. However, I think I am missing some forwarding rule that needs to be set up on **c2**.

> PS: Assume that the 'eth0' interface is locked down and is used only as the underlying interface to route packets of the 'peervpnXX' interface

Any help with regards to figuring this is highly appreciated.
Thank You in advance.

Shabir

[image: Complete Architecture explained above]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to find the issue.

Whilst adding the route for the container in the other subnet I haven't correctly specified the **gateway**. The *gateway* still points to the host machine in which docker is run *(see above figure)*. So I added the correct routing rule specific to the two end-containers - **c1 & c3**.

```
c1 - ip route add 10.23.0.0/24 via 10.12.0.1 dev peervpn12
c3 - ip route add 10.12.0.0/24 via 10.23.0.1 dev peervpn23
```

In the meantime, had to add the correct **FORWARD** rules in the c2 container's iptables:

```
 iptables -A FORWARD -s 10.12.0.2 -i peervpn12 -d 10.23.0.2 -o peervpn23 -j ACCEPT
 iptables -A FORWARD -s 10.23.0.2 -i peervpn23 -d 10.12.0.2 -o peervpn12 -j ACCEPT
```

With this setup I was able to achieve the flow I expected.

Thank You and I don't know why it's down-voted.
Maybe if I know the reason I can correct myself in future :)

Comment: If I've set `iptables`' `FORWARD` chain to globally accept, do I need the last two `iptables -A FORWARD`?